# How to track passed parameters via OnMethodBoundaryAspect?

Tags: postsharp

I am writing a profiling application and have already successfully traced method calls along with their time expenses. However, the Parameters collection in OnEntry() method is always NULL no matter what the method was called. How can I trace the parameters passed to the function (representation via .ToString() is ok) ? Here's the usage of my attribute in AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly:
```

MiniProfilerStep(
    AttributeTargetTypes = "BO*",
AttributeTargetExternalTypeAttributes =MulticastAttributes.All,
AttributeTargetExternalMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public | MulticastAttributes.Protected | MulticastAttributes.Static,
    AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public, 
AttributeTargetParameterAttributes =MulticastAttributes.Public | MulticastAttributes.OutParameter | MulticastAttributes.RefParameter,
    UnsupportedTargetAction =PostSharp.Aspects.UnsupportedTargetAction.Default
    )]

Comment: Isn't this your case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483769/why-is-the-compiler-optimizing-out-the-parameters-when-using-postsharp-with-an-a

Comment: If not, could you please share the source code of your `MiniProfilerStep` aspect?

Comment: Hi,
This is my MiniProfilerStepAttribute definition (copy&paste from PS samples):

https://pastebin.com/DxVPGVaa

Answer (score 1):

PostSharp optimizes away data that is not used. If you debug an aspect which doesn't access the properties in it's code, you'll always see the `Parameters` property being `null`.

After adding some code which accesses the `Parameters` property, the property should be populated.